# Why does Pelican ignore STATIC_PATHS?

Tags: static-site, pelican

I use [Pelican 4.2.0](https://pypi.org/project/pelican/#files) and just started [a new project](https://github.com/MartinThoma/chemie-gymnasium). I can `make html`, but the `output/` does not contain the directory `bilder/` which I specified in `pelicanconf.py` via `STATIC_PATHS`.

How can I make pelican include this folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pelican isn't ignoring `STATIC_PATHS`. Move your `bilder` and `doc` folders inside `content` and you will see the behavior you expect.

From the [Settings documentation](https://docs.getpelican.com/en/stable/settings.html) > `STATIC_PATHS` setting (emphasis mine):

> A list of directories ***(relative to `PATH`)*** in which to look for static files.

Your `PATH` setting is (correctly) set to the default value, which is your `content` folder. The folder specified in the `PATH` setting is where **all** your source content should live, but you have placed the `bilder` and `doc` folders at the root of your project directory, *outside* the `content` folder. Given your current project structure, Pelican looks inside your content, and since it doesn’t see the `bilder` and `doc` folders you set in `STATIC_PATHS`, it doesn’t do anything. You must move `bilder` and `doc` inside `content` in order for them to be copied via the `STATIC_PATHS` setting.

Comment: For future reference, I was reading the [pelican docs](https://docs.getpelican.com/en/latest/content.html#linking-to-static-files).

They say there to use something like this for links: `{static}/images/han.jpg` but for images src is enought with `/images/han.jpg`. It does not crystal clear for me on the docs, hope it helps.